# Possible to order column in range of another column?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a table with the following two columns: `about` and `create_time`.

I want to receive a list of rows that are ordered `length(about) DESC` but only per chunk of time. For example:

If I have the following rows:

| about | create_time |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Hey | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 |
| My name is Daniel | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| Hi | 2023-02-08 00:00:00 |
| What's up | 2023-03-02 00:00:00 |
| Hello | 2023-03-04 00:00:00 |
| I like to eat | 2023-11-05 00:00:00 |

And I want to order them per length of about but only in chunks of last 30 days, I'd expect to get the following:

| about | create_time |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | 2023-03-04 00:00:00 |
| What's up | 2023-03-02 00:00:00 |
| My name is Daniel | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| Hi | 2023-02-08 00:00:00 |
| Hey | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 |
| Hello | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| I like to eat | 2023-11-05 00:00:00 |

So they're ordered by length of about me but per chunk of 30 days, starting from `now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [**`date_bin()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) in Postgres 14 or later:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date_bin('30 days', create_time, now()) DESC, length(about) DESC;
```

See:

- [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75160734/939860)

Comment: Oh yes! You're right. I don't 100% understand how `date_bin` is doing what I want. Could you had a little bit of explanation?

Comment: Follow the links. It's all there.